# How to test styled components using Enzymes shallow and styled-component's ThemeProvider?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, styled-components

Is there a way to test the text content of a styled component using enzymes shallow method and the styled-components' ThemeProvider wrapper?

```
class MyComponent extends React.component {
    ...
    render(){
        return (
            <StyledComponent_A>
               <StyledComponent_B>
                   some text
               </StyledComponent_B>
            </StyledComponent_A>
        );
    }
}

test('text is \'some text\'', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>        
        <MyComponent />
    </ThemeProvider
    );
    const text = wrapper.dive().find(StyledComponent_B).text();
    expect(text).toBe('some text');
});
```

Comment: I believe this only works with Enzyme's mount().

Answer (score 1):

Using shallow your *text()* output is something like that `<styled.section />`

So you need to use **children()**, to get the content of the styled element.
Something like this:

```
const text = wrapper.find(StyledComponent_B).children().text();
expect(text).toBe('some text');
```